# Pivot Table range automatically saved as External Connection when renaming the Excel file

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am working on an Excel dashboard, which will be updated daily and save under a new name each time to include the date.

My problem is that whenever I save the workbook under a new name, an automatic external connection is created with the old version, rather then just using the same data that is in the current workbook.

So for example, my current workbook is called Dashboard. I can update/refresh my Pivot Tables with no issues at all. However, if I save my Dashboard to a new name (e.g. Dashboard 2016-08-31), then the range for my Pivot Table remains 'Dashboard'!AA:ZZ, so I cannot update my Pivot Table within my new version. It's automatically connected to the original version.

I have tried to rename the range of the Pivot Table, but again, it did not work.

The only way it works is to Change the Data Source in the new version of the Dashboard, but with 20+ Pivot Table and graphs, it's just not a viable option.

This is also a fairly new issue. I have been able to save and rename Excel workbook in the past with no issues.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!